# Does TestComplete support writing tests in Java?

Tags: testcomplete

I am trying to learn TestComplete automation tool, and I am familiar with the Java programming language. Does TestComplete supports writing tests in Java?

Answer (score 1):

TestComplete 12 (the current version at the time of writing) does not support writing tests in Java, although it supports [testing of Java applications](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/desktop/java/index.html).

Available [languages for writing tests](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/selecting-the-scripting-language.html) are:

- JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)
- Python 3.4
- JScript (Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript 3)
- VBScript
- DelphiScript
- C++Script and C#Script (not to be confused with C++ and C#)